# UPS shipping not working with base currency Euro

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, ups

Hello Everyone
I have set up UPS for my magento store. It works fine when base currency is USD but doesn't work when I change the base currency to Euro.
Can anyone tell me where I have to make changes for UPS to work with Euro?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are your currency rates set? I mean conversion from EUR to USD in System->Manage Currency->Rates?

Comment: I only have one more question that if it is necessary to set conversion rates? and why?

Comment: I honestly don't know. It was a shot in the dark :). (it seams I can shoot in the dark). You said it worked for a currency and not for an other. I immediately thought that maybe some currency is not set up properly. That's why I didn't add it as an answer. I just put the suggestion in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I look at my currency rates in System > Manage Currency > Rates, I found that it was null for USD.
[image]

So I added the current Rate for USD.
[image]

And it works now.

Comment: yep it worked for me too!